Routing fails to navigate to pages
I am new to angular so please be patient. I am trying to get links working in a new installation I have and it is not working. I can see the links to the two different pages but they do not work. I can manually type in the page name and it takes me to the other page but the links do not take me to the different pages. The following is code from my app.routes.ts, app.config.ts and main.ts.
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { TeamComponent } from './team/team.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'team', component: TeamComponent }

];

import { ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration, withEventReplay } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }), 
    provideRouter(routes), 
    provideClientHydration(withEventReplay())
  ]
};

import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
/**import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app/app.routes';*/

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch(err => console.error(err));

/**providers: [
  provideRouter(routes)
]*/


I figured it out. I needed to add RouterLink to my app.components.ts imports!
